# How to find multiple element in appium having same id in Python?

Tags: appium, appium-android, appium-ios, python-appium, appium-desktop

I am writing test code in Appium of an Andriod Project in python . The problem is that I am not able to access two button in two different Activity having same Id . I have tried to access the second button in this way.But none of them works. How to resolve the issue?
`driver.find_element_by_id("com.myapp.testApp:id/login[1]").click(), driver.find_element_by_class_name("android.widget.Button").click()
driver.find_element_by_xpath("(//button[@id='login'])[1]").click()
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//android.widget.Button[@text='Change Password']").click()`

Answer (score 1):

Use `.find_elements*`:

```
elements = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("xpath")
#check elements number
print(len(elements))
#click second element
elements[1].click()
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you try with textview:

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//android.widget.TextView[@text='Change Password']").click()
```

Comment: this does not work, I am talking about button, not about textview.

Answer (score 0):

If buttons texts are different, try by accessibility_id

`driver.find_element_by_accessibility_id("Login").click()`

`driver.find_element_by_accessibility_id("Change Password").click()`

OR

If you are familiar with uiautomator,

`driver.find_element_by_android_uiautomator('new UiSelector().resourceId("com.myapp.testApp:id/login[1]")')`

`driver.find_element_by_android_uiautomator('new UiSelector().resourceId("com.myapp.testApp:id/login[2]")')`

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `get` method with `findElements`:

```
driver.findElements(By.xpath("yourXpath]")).get(0).click();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do link this, It will give you proper Output:
Input is:

> d1 = driver.find_elements_by_id("com.application.zomato:id/price")
>
> itemtotalprice = d1[0].get_attribute("text")

Here, is my output:

> Mandarin Oak
> ₹200
> ₹166.75